# How to wait until job is done by retries and don't try to run other jobs

Tags: node.js, queue, nestjs, bull

I need to wait until current job will be done and don't run jobs which are also waiting to be executed.
When I `throw new Error('test')` current job(`job1`) will try to be executed again, because I set `backoff` and `attempts` and it is working, I can see how system is trying to execute `job1` again and again. But if in this time I will crate new job(`job2`), it will be executed immediately and will not wait for `job1`.
I need don't execute `job2` until I call `job1.done();`

Comment: Read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is implemented only in paid Pro version of Bull